# Why does Namba forcing preserve $\omega_1$?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

I have seen proofs that under CH, Namba forcing does not add reals, and thus preserves $\omega_1$.  How do you prove in ZFC alone that it preserves $\omega_1$?  I have also seen the stronger claim that it preserves stationary subsets of $\omega_1$, so please provide a reference for that also if possible.

Comment: http://boolesrings.org/mpawliuk/2012/10/18/namba-forcing-with-arnie-miller/ might be a place to start. It has notes from Arnie Miller's lectures about Namba forcing from a couple of years ago.

Comment: The argument for the preservation of $\omega_1$ is strewn about chapter XI of Shelah's *Proper and improper forcing* (preservation of stationary sets might also follow from this). Especially relevant are the definitions in section 2, Theorem 3.6 and Lemma 4.4.